# Cannot infer contextual base in reference to member 'fractionLength'

Tags: swift, apple-watch, watchos

I'm trying to follow this [screencast on building an app for Apple Watch](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2021/10009/).  I've updated Xcode to 13.3, but I'm getting an error that doesn't appear in the screencast.

> Cannot infer contextual base in reference to member 'fractionLength'

> Cannot infer contextual base in reference to member 'numeric'

> Extra argument 'numberFormat' in call

```
Text(
    Measurement(
        value: 47,
        unit: UnitEnergy.kilocalories
    ).formatted(
        .measurement(
            width: .abbreviated,
            usage: .workout,
            numberFormat: .numeric(precision: .fractionLength(0))
            )
        )
    )
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

maybe things have changed. You could try this instead:

```
Text(Measurement( value: 47, unit: UnitEnergy.kilocalories)
        .formatted(
            .measurement(
                width: .abbreviated,
                usage: .workout,
                numberFormatStyle: .number.precision(.fractionLength(0))
            )
        )
)
```

Comment: Thanks, whats the best way to track these changes to method names?

Comment: I have no idea.